# Remove rows with the same value in specific column from Datagridview.

Tags: sql, select, join

From This:

```
|-------------------------------|
| Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |     2     |    3    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |     2     |    4    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |     2     |    4    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |     5     |    6    |
|-------------------------------|
|   3     |     7     |    7    |
|-------------------------------|
```

How can I achieve this:

```
|-------------------------------|
| Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |     2     |    3    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |     5     |    6    |
|-------------------------------|
|   3     |     7     |    7    |
|-------------------------------|
```

Based only on the fact that Column 3 had 2 different rows with the value of 4.

This data grid can get up to the thousands so it would be nice to have a cost efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Are you doing this in the DataGridView or in SQL?

Comment: Why is it tagged with sql?

Comment: Do you have a unique key column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option based on your condition

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (         
              SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.Column3 = t.Column3
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
              )
```

Comment: WHERE t2.Column3 = t.Column3 isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example, I'd choose the minimum value for the 'duplicate containing' column:

```
select a.column1, a.column2, min(a.column3) as column3
from table as a
group by a.column1, a.column2
```